# Persistent mapping of hci names

Tags: linux, bluetooth, arch-linux, udev

I want a stable mapping between bluetooth hardware and hciX under /sys/class/bluetooth, similar to how wlanX maps to wifi chips.

I wrote a udev rule. The rule is matching correctly by vender/product. But how do i actually change the name? With wlan, i can simply specify NAME="wlan0". Thanks!

```
SUBSYSTEM="bluetooth", ATTRS{idVendor}=="foo", ATTRS={idProduct}="bar", RUN+="some_no_op_script.sh"
```

Answer (score 0):

Marcel Holtmann from www.bluez.org

> renaming of Bluetooth HCI interfaces is not supported. Just give the name as parameter to the script you are executing. udev actually knows the name of the Bluetooth HCI interface.